# Has Hanna of 1 Samuel 1 been a subject of study as role model of personal prayer?

Tags: prayer, 1-samuel

In 1 Samuel 1:9-15  we see the childless Hanna speaking to the Lord:

> <sup>**9**</sup> Once when they had finished eating and drinking in Shiloh, Hannah stood up. Now Eli the priest was sitting on his chair by the doorpost of the Lord’s house. <sup>**10**</sup> In her deep anguish, Hannah prayed to the Lord, weeping bitterly. <sup>**11**</sup> And she made a vow, saying, “Lord Almighty, if you will only look on your servant’s misery and remember me, and not forget your servant but give her a son, then I will give him to the Lord for all the days of his life, and no razor will ever be used on his head.” <sup>**12**</sup> As she kept on praying to the Lord, Eli observed her mouth. <sup>**13**</sup> Hannah was praying in her heart, and her lips were moving but her voice was not heard. Eli thought she was drunk <sup>**14**</sup> and said to her, “How long are you going to stay drunk? Put away your wine.” <sup>**15**</sup> “Not so, my lord,” Hannah replied, “I am a woman who is deeply troubled. I have not been drinking wine or beer; I was pouring out my soul to the Lord.

Of course, Jesus is the ultimate role model of personal prayer. But there are ordinary human beings who stand out in the communication with God in an exemplary way. Hanna is one.

Has Hanna of 1 Samuel 1 been a subject of study as a role model of personal prayer? Inputs from scholars of any denomination are welcome.